# Classic ASP Using Regular expression to add a space

Tags: regex, asp-classic, tinymce, strip-tags

I'm trying to do a replace with regular expressions in classic asp.

This is the code I've got so far

```
Public Function FixEmptyTags(value)
    Dim RegEx

    Set RegEx = New RegExp

    RegEx.Pattern = "<[^>]*\s"
    RegEx.Global = True

    FixEmptyTags = RegEx.Replace(value, "")
End Function
```

What I need is to find any empty tags which are not html tags like

```
<space
```

[image: memo field with empty tag]

[image: view source with decoded]

If it's followed by a space, TinyMCE it interprets as an unclosed tag so it converts it to

[image: after loading back from the db]

This is how it gets saved correctly in the db.

[image: db data]

This is what I see if I come back to the same page, so I lost part of the text

[image: after saving]

[image]

```
<space p=""></space>
```

If I add a space between the brackets and the text, it stops it from converting it to HTML. So I need to find the ones that are not closed and don't have a space and add one or stop tiny mce from converting it to html tags somehow.

```
< space
```

This is because we are using TinyMCE and to avoid user error and tinymce converting that into html tags.

I've tried to find a way to avoid TinyMCE converting that into html tags with no luck so I thought to simply add a space in between so when we open the record tinyMce doesn't convert that into html tags.

Hope it's clear enough.

Any help would be very much appreciated as always.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is just tried the [demo](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php) on the TinyMCE site and can't re-create what you are suggesting are you sure your not just missing some configuration in the TinyMCE editor? This is what I get using that demo `&lt;space&nbsp;` (when viewing the source).

Comment: The problem comes when reading the data back from the db. It decodes the &lt;space and turns it into <space at the same time it takes that as a tag so it is not actually visible in the tinymce. In the code what I see is <space p=""></space> as mentioned above.

Comment: @Lankymart I've included screenshots now.